# How to extract certain portion of a file that starts with "HDR" followed by a search keyword?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to extract portion of file that starts with `HDR` followed by search keyword using a batch file and Windows command interpreter?

Only certain HDR should be copied to another file with name `GoodHDR.txt`.
HDRs not included in searches should be copied also to another file with name `BadHDR.txt`.

For example, I have `HeaderList.txt` below and need to get `HEADER0001` and `HEADER0003` portions.

```
HDRHEADER0001          X004010850P
BEG00SAD202659801032017021699CANE
HDRHEADER0002          X004010850P
BEG00SAD202611701012017021499CANW
DTM01020170214
N1ST                              92   0642397236
N315829 RUE BELLERIVE
N4MONTREAL                      QCH1A5A6         CANADA
HDRHEADER0003          X004010850P
BEG00SAP521006901012017021399CANOUT  B16885
DTM01020170213
N1STCEGEP SAINT LAURENT           92   0642385892
```

**Expected outcome:**

`GoodHDR.txt` only contains `HEADER0001` and `HEADER0003`.

```
HDRHEADER0001          X004010850P
BEG00SAD202659801032017021699CANE
HDRHEADER0003          X004010850P
BEG00SAP521006901012017021399CANOUT  B16885
DTM01020170213
N1STCEGEP SAINT LAURENT           92   0642385892
```

`BadHDR.txt` contains `HEADER0002`:

```
HDRHEADER0002          X004010850P
BEG00SAD202611701012017021499CANW
DTM01020170214
N1ST                              92   0642397236
N315829 RUE BELLERIVE
N4MONTREAL
```

Comment: It is still unclear for me why the blocks of `HDRHEADER0001` and `HDRHEADER0003` are copied into `GoodHDR.txt` and why the block `HDRHEADER0002` is copied to `BadHDR.txt`. What makes the difference? What is the condition which determines if a header block is good or bad? I really don't understand what you mean with "To determine valid HDR, get the 10 characters after `HDR` and use it in a hard coded condition".

Comment: @Mofi, I will specify actually the search pattern, HDRHEADER0001 and HDRHEADER0003 in this case. Thus only chosen headers will be printed out to GoodHDR.txt and BadHDR.txt (HDRHEADER0002).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch code below expects to be started with the parameters `0001 0003` to produce the two output files from source file as posted in question.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFile=HeaderList.txt"
set "FoundFile=GoodHDR.txt"
set "IgnoreFile=BadHDR.txt"

if "%~1" == ""   goto ShowHelp
if "%~1" == "/?" goto ShowHelp

if not exist "%SourceFile%" goto NoHeaderList
del "%IgnoreFile%" 2>nul
del "%FoundFile%"  2>nul

rem Assign the headers passed as arguments to environment variables with
rem name HDR%~1X, HDR%~2X, HDR%~3X, etc. used later for quickly searching
rem for number of current header within the list of specified numbers.
rem All parameter strings not existing of exactly 4 digits are ignored.

set HeadersCount=0
:SetHeaders
set "HeaderNumber=%~1"
if "%HeaderNumber:~3,1%" == "" goto NextArgument
if not "%HeaderNumber:~4,1%" == "" goto NextArgument
for /F "delims=0123456789" %%I in ("%HeaderNumber%") do goto NextArgument
set "HDR%HeaderNumber%X=%HeaderNumber%"
set /A HeadersCount+=1
:NextArgument
shift /1
if not "%~1" == "" goto SetHeaders
if %HeadersCount% == 0 goto ShowHelp

rem Proces the header blocks in the source file.

set "OutputFile=%IgnoreFile%"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%SourceFile%") do call :ProcessLine "%%L"

rem Output a summary information of header block separation process.

if "%HeadersCount%" == "-1" set "HeadersCount="
if not defined HeadersCount (
    echo All header blocks found and written to file "%FoundFile%".
    goto EndBatch
)

set "SingularPlural= was"
if not %HeadersCount% == 1 set "SingularPlural=s were"
echo Following header block%SingularPlural% not found:
echo/
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%V in ('set HDR') do echo    %%V
goto EndBatch


rem ProcessLine is a subroutine called from main FOR loop with
rem a line read from source file as first and only parameter.

rem It compares the beginning of the line with HDRHEADER. The line is
rem written to active output file if it does not start with that string.

rem Otherwise the string after HDRHEADER is extracted from the
rem line and searched in list of HDR environment variables.

rem Is the header in list of environment variables, this line and all
rem following lines up to next header line or end of source file are
rem written to file with found header blocks.

rem Otherwise the current header line and all following lines up to
rem next header line or end of source file are written to file with
rem header blocks to ignore.

rem Once all header blocks to find are indeed found and written completely
rem to the file for found header blocks, all remaining lines of source file
rem are written to the ignore file without further evaluation.

:ProcessLine
if not defined HeadersCount (
    >>"%OutputFile%" echo %~1
    goto :EOF
)
set "Line=%~1"
if not "%Line:~0,9%" == "HDRHEADER" (
    >>"%OutputFile%" echo %~1
    goto :EOF
)
set "HeaderLine=%Line:~9%"
for /F %%N in ("%HeaderLine%") do set "HeaderNumber=%%N"

set "OutputFile=%IgnoreFile%"
for /F %%N in ('set HDR%HeaderNumber%X 2^>nul') do (
    set "HDR%HeaderNumber%X="
    set /A HeadersCount-=1
    set "OutputFile=%FoundFile%"
)
>>"%OutputFile%" echo %~1
if %HeadersCount% == 0 (
    set "HeadersCount=-1"
) else if %HeadersCount% == -1 (
    set "HeadersCount="
)
goto :EOF


:NoHeaderList
echo Error: The file "%SourceFile%" could not be not found in directory:
echo/
echo %CD%
goto EndBatch


:ShowHelp
echo Searches for specified headers in "%SourceFile%" and writes the
echo found header blocks to file "%FoundFile%" and all other to file
echo "%IgnoreFile%" and outputs the header blocks not found in file.
echo/
echo %~n0 XXXX [YYYY] [ZZZZ] [...]
echo/
echo %~nx0 must be called with at least one header number.
echo Only numbers with 4 digits are accepted as parameters.

:EndBatch
echo/
endlocal
pause
```

The redirection operator `>>` and the current name of the output file is specified at beginning of all lines which print with command **ECHO** the current line to avoid appending a trailing space on each line written to an output file and get the line printing nevertheless working if a line ends with `1`, `2`, `3`, ...

Some additional notes about limitations on usage of this code:

1. The batch code is written with avoiding the usage of delayed expansion to be able to easily process also lines containing an exclamation mark. The disadvantage of not using delayed expansion is that lines containing characters in a line with a special meaning on command line like `&`, `>`, `<`, `|`, etc. result in wrong output and can even produce additional, unwanted files in current directory.
   It would be of course possible to extend the batch code to work also for lines in source file containing any ANSI character, but this is not necessary according to source file example which does not contain any "poison" character.
2. **FOR** ignores empty lines on reading lines from a text file. So the code as is produces 1 or 2 output files with no empty lines copied from source file.
3. The main **FOR** loop reading the lines from source file skips all lines starting with a semicolon. If this could be a problem, specify on **FOR** command line reading the lines from source file before `delims=` the parameter `eol=` with a character which definitely never exists at beginning of a line in source file. See help of command **FOR** displayed on running in a command prompt window `for /?` for details on parameters of `set /F` like `eol=`, `delims=` and `tokens=`.
4. The length of a string assigned to an environment variable plus equal sign plus name of environment variable is limited to 8192 characters. For that reason this batch code can't be used for a source file with lines longer than 8187 characters.
5. The length of a command line is also limited. The maximum length depends on version of Windows. So this batch file can't be used with a very large number of header numbers.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `shift /?`

Read also the Microsoft documentation page about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for details about `>>` and `2>nul` and `2^>nul` with redirection operator `>` being escaped with caret character `^` for being interpreted as literal character on parsing **FOR** command line, but as redirection operator later on execution of command **SET** by command **FOR**.

Comment: works like a charm! Appreciate it especially the explanation it follows.